# react-navigation How to add a dynamic test id to the tabBarTestID

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using react-navigation and I want to add a dynamic test id to the tabBarTesID when that specific tab is focused and unfocused because the test team cannot see a difference when a specific tab bar is taped or not.

I would like to add it in the navigator, here:

```
Home: {
screen: HomeTab,
navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
  tabBarTestID: 'bottom-tab-bar-home',
  tabBarAccessibilityLabel: 'bottom-tab-bar-home',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => <TabIcon type='menu_home' isActive={focused} />,
  tabBarVisible: isTabBarVisible(navigation),
  tabBarLabel: i18n.t('tab_bar_home')
})
```

}

Does somebody know if react-navigation sets an attribute automatically if a tab was tapped?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: was this fixed? I am looking for something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help someone, we have added test id's only for the bottom tabs and we used the following properties:

For **iOS**

- set a test id for the **tabBarTestID**

For **android**

- set a test id for the **tabBarAccessibilityLabel**

  ```
  const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeStack,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        ...setTestID(testIDs.homeTabBarButton) ... 


  const setTestID = (testID = '') => {
      if (isIOS) {
        return {
          tabBarTestID: testID
        };
      }
      return {
        tabBarAccessibilityLabel: testID
      };
    };
  ```